# iterator has item but hasnext doesn't return true

Tags: java, android, iterator

[image]

while(iter.hasNext())  **iterator has items but condition doesn't work. What's wrong there?**

```
iter= productDataList.iterator();

public void CalcPrice(View v){
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            if(iter.next().name.equals(pName)){
                price=Integer.parseInt(iter.next().price);
            }
        }
        edPrice.setText("Tutar : "+price);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `iter.next()` twice for the same data.

Do it as follows:

```
iter= productDataList.iterator();

public void CalcPrice(View v){
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Product productData = iter.next()
        if(productData.name.equals(pName)){
            price=Integer.parseInt(productData.price);
            break;
        }
    }
    edPrice.setText("Tutar : "+price);
}
```

Comment: Values this.iter.hasnext(): https://ibb.co/R9L9Jz8
this.iter.next(): https://ibb.co/WFs16sB

Comment: There must be some other problem. Post the complete code and I will look into it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope, it fixes your issue.

Comment: Ty for help. But it still return false.

Comment: It seems there is some confusion. Put a sysout statement e.g. `System.out.println("True");` as the first line inside the `while` loop and you will find that it does get executed proving that `iter.hasNext()` is returning `true`. Feel free to comment in case there is still any doubt.

Comment: it return that error 'Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
        at com.mustafagunel.mustafagunel.PriceCheckActivity.CalcPrice(PriceCheckActivity.java:114)' 
there should be wrong something in my iterator declaration.